How to make a new database using Code First in WinForms
I want to make a MSSQL using code-first approach.
I have defined two models - Product and Category and then defined the DbContext as you can see below:
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

But I have not managed to find how and where to put the connection string and update the database after creating a migration.

Getting Started with EF Core - everything is here.

Hello, my bad I forgot to mention that I want to make make it using MSSQL.

Well, I just had to override the OnConfiguring method and add the connection string there.
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Connection String...");
}

